# TigerVNC colours distorted and hardly to read

Tags: xubuntu, windows, vnc, colors

I'm using TigerVNC Viewer to connect from Windows 10 to my Xubuntu PC. It works fine, except with some colors. For example, when opening a configuration file with `vim`, the strings were shown in red. Especially the comments are really annoying, because the dark blue color is nearly unreadable:

[image]

The used Numix theme doesn't cause this. For comparisation, I opened the same file on a native screen, directly connected to the same Xubuntu machine:

[image]

#### How can I fix this to make the remote VNC colors look like the native ones from Xfce?

I already looked in the VNC viewer settings and couldn't find any suspicious settings: Colors are already set to full. Compression were enabled. For testing purpose I disabled both, no effect. The same for *Auto select*.

[image]

Comment: That isn't related to your gui, but the colored scheme used in `vim`.  Change your vim theme.

Comment: You're right! But strangely `:colo` shows `default` on both VNC and direct connection. Both use the same user account. By randomly trying the avaliable themes I found that the theme from the second secreen is called `ron`. By setting `colo ron` in my `~/.vimrc` it's now consistent on both sessions. I don't full understand why the physical session uses `ron` and vnc not, but this works - thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable full-color support in Vim?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67/how-do-i-enable-full-color-support-in-vim)