# Error message on startup using a Ubuntu USB stick

Tags: boot

I have downloaded this file : ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso to install Unbuntu on an old computer. After startup, I have had this message : This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

Is it related to my CPU capabilities ? May I install an 32 bits version ?
If yes, is it possible to have Unity as 32 bits version ?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 18.04 32-bit version. You can try Lubuntu, or Xubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is still supported, is available as x86 (ie. 32-bits) and comes with Unity (7) by default.  It reaches EOL on 2021-April but is an option. Ubuntu flavors are your next suggestion as Pilot6 suggested; the lightest is Lubuntu, followed by Xubuntu, and they have releases for 18.04 LTS however flavors only have 3 years of support, thus EOL also in 2021-April.  https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours  Yes you can technically run Unity 7 on x86 (32-bits), but having done so, I would strongly recommend a *lighter* flavor.

Comment: Thanks, what I need is a system that I can update time to time (even in 32b).

Answer (score 0):

> Try 32-bit (i386) version.
> make sure usb burn with rufus or etcher.
>
> if not work try ubuntu 16.04.
> .
> .
> Thanks

Answer (score 0):

U can download mini ubuntu 18.04 32 bit(netboot).
Can u check this https://askubuntu.com/questions/101a4149/how-come-ubuntu-18-04-lts-has-a-32bit-iso-installer.